# Strange bug in CSS transform - 1 pixel plus with some transparency

Tags: html, css, transform

The problem is that I'm trying to make a line to mark the items in a list and somehow appears a two-pixel stripe instead of a one-pixel and looks it have some alpha.

I tried to use scale to get the line more skinny.

https://codepen.io/vendramini/pen/XWrywXV

index.html

```html
<div class="list-wrapper">
<ul>
  <li>Do shopping</li>
  <li class="marked">Wash the dishes</li>
  <li class="marked-without-transform">Take a shower</li>
  <li>Sleep</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

style.scss

```
.marked{

  position: relative;
  &:before{
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
  }
}

.marked-without-transform{

  position: relative;
  &:before{
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    // transform: translateY(-50%);
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
  }
}

.list-wrapper{
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

I want to know why it is happening, sounds like a bug. The code shows more than words. I expect to have a straight line of 1 pixel than 2.

Comment: Why not trying `text-decoration: line-through;` instead of custom styling?

Comment: Nope, I want to make it using a transition with some interaction involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's aliasing from the transform trying to handle a percentage instead of a fixed pixel measurement. A quickie workaround if you wanted to keep the same strategy would be like;

```css
.marked, .marked-without-transform {
  position: relative;
}

.marked:before, .marked-without-transform:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Workaround */
.marked:before {
    border-top: red 1px solid;
}

/* Aliasing issue */
.marked-without-transform:before {
    background-color: red;
}

.list-wrapper {
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-wrapper">
<ul>
  <li>Do shopping</li>
  <li class="marked">Wash the dishes</li>
  <li class="marked-without-transform">Take a shower</li>
  <li>Sleep</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just an observation: this trick you did only works border-top, with border-bottom appears the same problem of height. :)

Comment: @LucasVendramini huh, shouldn't, and I'm not seeing it that way on my end, what browser and do you have some scaling going on somewhere or something?

Comment: @ChrisV Google Chrome v.76.0.3809.132 64 bits. I used height: 0 in this case, makes sense?